# Unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType' on Custom Save - Django Form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a custom save on Django form because I have some variables that depends on other's values. When I use the admin form, it works perfectly, all the variables on my custom save are created with no problems and with the correct values. But when I use my form (the one from my template), I get the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/monique/.local/share/virtualenvs/SISTEMA-rPBRM75u/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/monique/.local/share/virtualenvs/SISTEMA-rPBRM75u/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/monique/MEGA/FORREST/SISTEMA/sepProdMachos/views.py", line 17, in add
    obj = form.save()
  File "/home/monique/.local/share/virtualenvs/SISTEMA-rPBRM75u/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 468, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "/home/monique/MEGA/FORREST/SISTEMA/sepProdMachos/models.py", line 50, in save
    self.porcContaminacao = (self.nFemeasCQ*100)/self.amostragemTotal

Exception Type: TypeError at /sepProdMachos/add/
Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

My model code is:

```
from hatching.models import Hatching
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class SepProdMachos(models.Model):
    
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    hatching = models.OneToOneField(Hatching, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)

    data = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    inicio = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    fim = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    nBandejas = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    bandejasDescartadas = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    bandejasSeparadas = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    mlMachos  = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    mlMachosRepassado  = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    mlFemeas =  models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    nOperadores = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    nFemeasCQ = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    amostragemTotal = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    porcContaminacao = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    nMachosAliquota = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    nAliquotas = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    aliquotaIncompleta = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    totalMacho = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    porcRendimento = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.hatching.data.strftime('%d/%m/%y')}-{self.hatching.cor}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.bandejasSeparadas is None:
            self.bandejasSeparadas = self.nBandejas - self.bandejasDescartadas

        if self.porcContaminacao is None:
            self.porcContaminacao = (self.nFemeasCQ*100)/self.amostragemTotal

        if self.totalMacho is None:
            self.totalMacho = (self.nMachosAliquota*self.nAliquotas)+self.aliquotaIncompleta+self.amostragemTotal

        if self.porcRendimento is None:
            self.porcRendimento = (self.totalMacho*100)/(self.nBandejas*10000)

        super(SepProdMachos, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My form code is:

```
from django import forms
from hatching.models import Hatching

from .models import SepProdMachos

operadoresChoices=(
    (1,1),
    (2,2),
    (3,3),
    (4,4),
    (5,5),
)

class SepProdMachosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    hatching = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Hatching.objects.all().order_by('created'), initial=0)
        
    data = forms.DateInput()
    inicio = forms.TimeInput()
    fim = forms.TimeInput()

    nBandejas = forms.IntegerField()
    bandejasDescartadas = forms.IntegerField(initial=0)

    mlMachos  = forms.FloatField()
    mlMachosRepassado  = forms.FloatField()
    mlFemeas =  forms.FloatField()
    nOperadores = forms.ChoiceField(choices=operadoresChoices)
    nFemeasCQ = forms.IntegerField()
    amostragemTotal = forms.IntegerField()

    nMachosAliquota = forms.IntegerField()
    nAliquotas = forms.IntegerField()
    aliquotaIncompleta = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = SepProdMachos
        fields = [
            'data',
            'inicio',
            'fim',
            'nBandejas',
            'bandejasDescartadas',
            'mlMachos',
            'mlFemeas',
            'nOperadores',
            'nFemeasCQ',
            'nMachosAliquota',
            'aliquotaIncompleta',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'data': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
            'inicio': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
            'fim': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
            'nBandejas': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'number'}),
            'nOperadores': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'custom-select'}),

        }
```

And my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<title>Adicionar</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    </header>

    <h1>Separação e Produção de Machos</h1>

    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- {{ form|crispy }} -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row card-branco">
                <h3>Informações gerais</h3>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Lote</label>
                    {{ form.hatching }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Data</label>
                    {{ form.data }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Horário de início </label>
                    {{ form.inicio }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Horário de fim</label>
                    {{ form.fim }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col card-branco">
                    <h3>Bandejas</h3>
                    <label>Número de bandejas</label>
                    {{ form.nBandejas }}
                    <label>Bandejas descartadas</label>
                    {{ form.bandejasDescartadas }}
                </div>
                <div class="col card-branco">
                    <h3>Coleta de Machos</h3>
                    <label>Ml de machos</label>
                    {{ form.mlMachos }}
                    <label>Ml de machos repassados</label>
                    {{ form.mlMachosRepassado }}
                    <label>Ml de fêmeas</label>
                    {{ form.mlFemeas }}
                    <label>Número de operadores</label>
                </br>
                    {{ form.nOperadores}}
                </div>
                <div class="col card-branco">
                    <h3>Controle de Qualidade</h3>
                    <label>Número de fêmeas encontradas no controle de qualidade</label>
                    {{ form.nFemeasCQ }}
                    <label>Amostragem total</label>
                    {{ form.amostragemTotal }}
                </div>
                <div class="col card-branco">
                    <h3>Finalização</h3>
                    <label>Número de machos por alíquota</label>
                    {{ form.nMachosAliquota }}
                    <label>Número de alíquotas</label>
                    {{ form.nAliquotas }}
                    <label>Número de machos na alíquota incompleta</label>
                    {{ form.aliquotaIncompleta }}
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-branco">SALVAR</button>
    </div>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Share the `sepProdMachos/models.py` models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On forms.py, I forgot to write the fields `amostragemTotal` and `nAliquotas` in the class `Meta`.